# Change wordpress wp-admin login title

Tags: php, html, wordpress

How can I change my wordpress title of my wp-admin?

I just want to edit the -- Wordpress from the title and change the symbol < that is used.

The following image explains what I'm talking about.

[image: the image that explains]

I tried this code:

```
function my_admin_title($admin_title, $title)
{
    return get_bloginfo('name').' &bull; '.$title;
}
```

But he only removes from the admin panel, not admin login.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `login_title` filter (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/login_title/). Reconstruct the title as needed. This can go in the `functions.php` file or a custom plugin. It is recommended to use a child theme if editing theme files. Example:

```
add_filter('login_title', custom_login_title, 99);
function custom_login_title($origtitle) { 

    return get_bloginfo('name');

}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you man!!
One question, can i put something in -- Wordpress place? Like Website Title -- Other word ?

Comment: Ok, yes. You can return anything as the new title. Example: `return 'Login page - ' . get_bloginfo('description') . ' - ' . get_bloginfo('name');` Is that like what you mean? I'm not positive I followed your question correctly.

Comment: If someone get this:
{ Warning: Use of undefined constant custom_login_title - assumed 'custom_login_title' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) } you can add single quotation to the filter as follow: { add_filter('login_title', 'custom_login_title', 99); }